# "Docker-compose up" does not pull images everytime , it recreates a pulled image

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following contents:

```
FROM <docker-registry>/<image>:latest
COPY mv setup /root/
RUN setup
```

When I do a `docker-compose up -d`, Docker pulls the image and executes the steps.

When I do a `docker-compose stop` and bring it back up, docker-compose dos not pull the latest image again. This is a problem for me as I will need a new image to be downloaded. The only way for me to do this is to blow up boot2docker vm and start over again.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `docker-compose pull` command to pull remote image, use `docker-compose build` command to build local image, 
then use `docker-compose up -d` to recreate your container.

```
$ cd /path/to/folder

$ cat docker-compose.yml
myapp:
  build: .
  links:
    - redis    
redis:
  image: redis

# pull lastest image
$ docker-compose pull redis

# build your image
$ docker-compose build myapp

# recreate containers
$ docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: The above steps will not recreate the container . you will have to do a "docker-compose build --no-cache" to recreate the containers

Answer (score 5):

Docker Compose version 1.5.0rc1 can now pull latest images referenced in Dockerfiles on build by using `docker-compose build --pull`.

Before 1.5.0rc1 `docker-compose` could not force a Dockerfile service to get the latest image. I had to use `docker pull <image>`.

Once the new imaged has been pulled, then you can rebuild with `docker-compose build`. Cache should be totally invalidated because step 0's FROM hash has changed, if the image has changed.